# twig and handlebars how to include a template

Tags: twig

First I know `{% raw %}`.
My problem is that I use backbone on the front end and use quite a lot of Handlebars templates. On my main twig template I've got:

```
{% block templates %}

<script id="element" type="text/template">
    {% include "ticket/element.html.twig" %}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and then I've got the template ticket/element.html.twig:

```
<ul>
  <li class="ref_code">{{ ref_code }}</li>
  <li class="names">{{ firstname}} {{ lastname}}</li>
  <li class="email">{{ email }}</li>
<ul>
```

My question is: Is it possible to put the equivalent of `{%raw%}` directly on the include declaration. For eg: `{% include "ticket/element.html.twig" | raw %}`
That would be great because it would enable me to use ticket/element.html.twig as a template on back-end and on front-end.

It is a bit of a silly question but I was just wondering...

Answer (score 3):

I know of no way to filter an include but I'm no expert on Twig.  What about putting the `{% raw %}` in your inner template?

```
<ul>
{% raw %}
  <li class="ref_code">{{ ref_code }}</li>
  <li class="names">{{ firstname}} {{ lastname}}</li>
  <li class="email">{{ email }}</li>
{% endraw %}
<ul>
```

Comment: I thought about that but the problem with that is that I can't reuse the template on the front side as there is a twig specific expression.
There was many limitations in reusing the templates on both sides I therefore gave up on that. 
However I'd still be interested to know if it is possible

Comment: Now from version 1.12, the {% verbatim %} tag has be to used. Check the following link: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html